# 2 Level CSS Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu for which I am trying to add another level roughly named "sub sub" by hovering on "Product 1". It's showing the "sub sub" menu, but it is not disappearing when the mouse hovers over "Product 2" or "Product 3". I don't know what I am doing wrong with the code.

Please have a look at HTML and CSS and let me know if anyone can help?

```
<div class="navigation">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">products</a>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">product 1</a>
                        <div>
                        <a href="#">sub sub</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">product 2</a>
                        <a href="#">product 3</a>

                 </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            </li>
        </div>
```

CSS is here:

```
.navigation {
            float: right;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 110px 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            }

.navigation li {
            font-family: "Segoe UI Web Regular","Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: Maroon;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 50px;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            z-index:999;
            }

.navigation li > a {
        color: #505050;
        text-decoration: none;
            }

.navigation li:hover > a 
            {
            color:#D30404;
            }

.navigation li > div a {
            color: #505050;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            padding: 4px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            }

.navigation li:hover > div {
            color: #D30404;
        display: block;
            }

.navigation li > div a:hover {
         color: #fff;
         background-color: #D30404;
            }

.navigation li > div {
         background-color:rgb(250, 250, 250);
         display: none;
         width: 110px;
         position: absolute;
             }

.navigation li div div a 
             {
             background-color:rgb(250, 250, 250);
         display: none;
         width: 110px;
         position: relative;
             }

.navigation li div:hover > div a
             {
             display: block;
             position: absolute;
             margin-left: 110px;
             top: -2px;
             }
```

Comment: Always include a link to a jsfiddle for this kind of stuff

Comment: Fiddle for others working through this http://jsfiddle.net/K7kPJ/

Answer (score 1):

Got it! (Forgive me for changing your code so much.) http://jsfiddle.net/K7kPJ/4/

```
.navigation {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }

.navigation li {
            font-family: "Segoe UI Web Regular","Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: Maroon;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 50px;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            z-index:999;
            }

.navigation li > a {
        color: #505050;
        text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
            }

.navigation li:hover > a 
            {
            color:#D30404;
            }

.navigation li > div a {
            color: #505050;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            padding: 4px;

            }


.navigation li > div a:hover {
         color: #fff;
         background-color: #D30404;
            }

.navigation li > div {
         background-color:rgb(250, 250, 250);
         display: none;
         width: 110px;
         position: absolute;
             }

.navigation li div div
             {
             background-color:rgb(250, 250, 250);
         display: none;
         width: 110px;
         position: absolute;
   left:110px;
    top:0;
             }

.navigation li a:hover + div, .navigation li div:hover
             {
             display: block;
             }
```

Comment: sub sub stays open for me when hovering over products > products 2.

Comment: weird...there you've got me stumped. I'm looking at it right now :/

Comment: Sorry I am new that's why didn't know to use jsfiddle.

Comment: no problem. Give me a few minutes here. Still trying to figure this out

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I am waiting :)

Comment: How's that look. I think I got it!

Comment: Just going to add another div for Product 2. Hope it would work correctly!

Comment: No, adding another div under Product 2, it's pointing me to the same class .navigation li div div   and it's not creating a new div right after "Product 2" sub-menu.